# Multiple File Upload in FTP Using CMD

Tags: ftp

I've a large number of files, over 10,000, which I want to upload in FTP server. Now, I can't zip those files & upload it as I've to read those files individually in SAS software for my analysis.

If I use mput command, then the prompt as me to say "y" each time it tries to upload the file. This is very cumbersome. Is there any method by which it automatically upload the files without I've to manually entering "y" each time file wants to upload?

The command I was using was:

```
ftp ftp.myftp.com  *my ftp server name
username:myusername
password:mypassword
ftp> lcd c:\local_folder
ftp> mput *.*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [prompt](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm#prompt) command before mput to turn off the prompting behaviour.